# EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue after refactoring

Tags: c++, marmalade

The following code works in a the Marmalade simulator (I'm on OSX using x-code)

```
bool PictureDictionary::OnTableSelect(CTable* table, int tab){
    //if something is selected, look up the item, and display it
    //also change the search to the selected item
    if(-1 < tab){

        // if a term is selected, set the search text field to the term
        CString term = m_SearchResults.GetString(tab);

        if(m_currentWord != (char*)term.Get()){
            m_currentWord = (char *)term.Get();
            m_searchTextField->SetAttribute("text", term);

            char* normalizedTerm = (char *)term.Get();
            char* imagePath;
            sprintf(imagePath,"images/%s.jpg", normalizedTerm);

            if(m_ImageAttached){
                m_Image->SetAttribute("image", (const char*)imagePath);
            } else {
                m_Image = CreateImage(CAttributes()
                                      .Set("name",    "picture")
                                      .Set("x1",      "0")
                                      .Set("x2", "0")
                                      .Set("y1",      "50%")
                                      .Set("image", (const char*)imagePath)
                                      );
                m_SearchView->AddChild(m_Image);
                m_ImageAttached = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I run the simulator, and select an item from the table, the image appears, and changes when I select a different item.  When I go to refactor, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1…..) Error

```
bool PictureDictionary::OnTableSelect(CTable* table, int tab){
    //if something is selected, look up the item, and display it
    //also change the search to the selected item
    if(-1 < tab){

        // if a term is selected, set the search text field to the term
        CString term = m_SearchResults.GetString(tab);

        if(m_currentWord != (char*)term.Get()){
            m_currentWord = (char *)term.Get();
            m_searchTextField->SetAttribute("text", term);        

            char* normalizedTerm = (char *)term.Get();
            char* imagePath;
            sprintf(imagePath,"images/%s.jpg", normalizedTerm);

            UpdatePictureView(imagePath);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void PictureDictionary::UpdatePictureView(char* imagePath){
    if(m_ImageAttached){
        m_Image->SetAttribute("image", (const char*)imagePath);
    } else {
        m_Image = CreateImage(CAttributes()
                              .Set("name",    "picture")
                              .Set("x1",      "0")
                              .Set("x2", "0")
                              .Set("y1",      "50%")
                              .Set("image", (const char*)imagePath)
                              );
        m_SearchView->AddChild(m_Image);
        m_ImageAttached = true;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to clean up the code without getting these issues?

**Edit RE Comments about uninitialized variables**:
m_ImageAttached was initialized to false in the constructor, unless I'm doing something wrong.  Also, changing the condition to check if m_Image!=NULL also throws the same error.

main.cpp:

```
PictureDictionary pictDict(myApp, &dictionary);
```

Constructor for PictureDictionary:

```
PictureDictionary::PictureDictionary(CAppPtr app,Dictionary::Dictionary* dictionary){
    m_App = app;
    m_Dictionary = dictionary;
    m_currentWord = "";
    m_ImageAttached = false;
}
```

Comment: I suspect that m_ImageAttached is not properly initialized, so welcome in the land of undefined behavior, where a simple refactoring can lead to crashes. Make sure to initialize it to false.

Comment: rather than having two variable, m_Image and m_ImageAttached, you'd probably better have only one: m_Image, as m_ImageAttached == (m_Image!=NULL). That way, you won't have an uninitialized variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imagePath` is an unitialized pointer, in both snippets. Any attempt to dereference is undefined behaviour. It just appeared to *work* in the first snippet. Use an array or populate a `std::string` instead:

```
std::string imagePath(std::string("images/") + normalizedTerm + ".jpg");
```

And use `std::string::c_str()` if access to the underlying `const char*` is required.

Comment: @tandoan Just to add to this correct answer, the refactoring did not introduce the error, the refactoring just exposed a problem that was always there.  `sprintf(imagePath,"images/%s.jpg", normalizedTerm);` to an uninitialized `imagePath` (which points to random memory) is going to corrupt *something*, it just didn't happen to crash the program previously.